# How do I run a parameter as a method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, watir

I need to know how to pass in called methods as an array and then run that code inside of an instantiated class.

Background code (simplified for example):

```
class API
    def putsWords(myWords)
        puts myWords
    end

 end

class TestAssert
    def multiply(num1, num2)
        puts (num1 * num2)
    end
end
```

(In the real world, API and TestAssert are both hundreds of lines of methods using and combining commands to interact with web pages via Watir.)

What I am failing to get to work right now:

```
require_relative 'API'
require_relative 'Asserts'
require_relative 'LoggingIn'

class Step

    def initialize(actionArray, checkArray=nil)
        @interact = API.new
        asserting = TestAssert.new
        actionArray.each do |action|
            @interact.action
        end
        checkArray.each do |check|
            @asserting.check
        end 
    end 
end 

@myActionArray = Array.new

@myActionArray << putsWords("Hello")
    @myActionArray << putsWords("World")


@myAssertArray = Array.new

@myAssertArray << multiply(7, 3)


step1 = Step.new(@myActionArray, @myAssertArray)
```

This isn't working.  I get there error message "undefined method 'action' "

How can I make this work?

(If you're curious why I'm not using Proc or a lambda, I *was* doing that, but our architect said that that isn't the correct way to do it and I need to do it this way.)

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use [send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-send) to send an arbitrary message to your objects, and change your input arrays:

```
@myActionArray = Array.new
@myActionArray << ["oppAndQuote", "Acme", "QuoteTest", "", "", ""]


@myAssertArray = Array.new
@myAssertArray << ["assertOnPage", "QuoteTest", "didnt work"]
```

Then you can just use `send` and splat out the array into an argument list:

```
@interact.send(*action)
...
@asserting.send(*check)
```

Frankly, I think the lambda path is better, but if your architect wants it done this way, this is how you'd do it.

Comment: The way you wrote it, it is as if each of the items goes into the array separately, but that isn't the case.  One item in the array is: oppAndQuote("Acme", "QuoteTest", "", "", "".  Or, in the simplified version: putsWords("Hello).  

When I try to do that, I get "undefined method 'oppAndQuote' for main:Object".

Comment: send's signature is `send(method_name, *args)`, so if you have an array of `[methodname, arg1, arg2, ..., argn]`, you can splat it into `send` to invoke the method with those parameters. Make sure it's a string or symbol, and that you're not trying to invoke the actual method.